# displaying fields on front end-Prestashop

Tags: frontend, prestashop-1.6

i am new to prestashop and am trying to create an ecomm by myself,  i am using a marketplace and have added the product reference as an author name and is successfully being displayed in the back-end. But my problem is that it isn't being displayed at the front end (product page).
But when these fields are being created by the admin, all fields are displayed in the produce page.
The screenshot of the front and back-end is attached below.[the author and isbn fields are appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CKMS.png)

[But here the author and isbn are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z451q.png)

PLEASEE HELP

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you have some problem in your code. First of all you should read something about prestashop and creating shops. Next step is to fix a problem in a file **smarty_internal_templatebase.php** in line **53**.

As I can see you have a problem with product's publisher. I assume your code looks like this:

```
<p id="publisher">{$product->publisher}</p>

// in other words
<p id="publisher">[show publisher no matter what]</p>
```

In the scenario above, we can clearly see that if a product we want to show doesn't have a publisher, then we are stuck.

I recommend your code to look this way:

```
<p id="publisher">{if $product->publisher}{$product->publisher}{else}No publisher{/if}</p>

// again in other words
<p id="publisher">[if publisher exists, show it, else write something else]</p>
```

Try to check on that and let us know what you've found.

Cheers, Mentozz.